# basic jQuery function not responding

Tags: jquery

I would like my jQuery function to turn check the attribute of the checkbox and if checked make a text with the id ="activate_post_checkbox_text" black. otherwise i would like the text to be grey.

jQuery

```
function checkedDark () {
    if($("#activate_post_checkbox").attr("checked")) {
            $("#activate_post_checkbox_text").style.color = "#000";
    } else {
            $("#activate_post_checkbox_text").style.color = "#666";
    }

}
```

HTML

```
<li class="activate_post_checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" id="activate_post_checkbox" value="active" onClick="valueChange();" /><span id="activate_post_checkbox_text">Make my posting active immediately.</span>
</li>
```

this is how it looks right now in my script type="text/javascript" area on the top of my page.

```
function checkedDark () {

$('#activate_post_checkbox')
.click(valueChange)
.click(function(){

  $("#activate_post_checkbox_text").css('color', this.checked ? '#000' : '#666');

});


}
```

Comment: In your example your onclick value and your functionname are different.  Is that the same in your actual code?

Comment: You have a `class` name on `li` that is exactly identical to the `id` name on the `input`.  It may lead to confusion in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your markup you are calling `valueChange` method onclick and you are wrtting the code in `checkedDark` method. I hope I am not missing anything.

Instead of having inline onclick statement use jQuery to attach click handler. Inside the handler you can use `this.checked` to see if the checkbox is checked or not and use `css` jQuery method to set the text color of the required element.

Markup change

```
<li class="activate_post_checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" id="activate_post_checkbox" value="active"/><span id="activate_post_checkbox_text">Make my posting active immediately.</span>
</li>
```

JS

```
$('#activate_post_checkbox')
.click(valueChange)
.click(function(){

  $("#activate_post_checkbox_text").css('color', this.checked ? '#000' : '#666');

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nzTMj/)**

Comment: valueChange is a different function using javascript

Comment: Ok got it. Check my answer hope that makes sense to you.

Comment: When do you call `checkedDark` method?

Comment: I have it at the top of my page with all my other javascripts / jQuery functions

Comment: function checkedDark () {

$('#activate_post_checkbox')
.click(valueChange)
.click(function(){

  $("#activate_post_checkbox_text").css('color', this.checked ? '#000' : '#666');

});


}

Comment: I want to know when do you call this method `checkedDark`. Anyways use my code it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkedDark () {
    if($('#activate_post_checkbox').is(':checked')) {
            $("#activate_post_checkbox_text").css('color', '#000');
    } else {
            $("#activate_post_checkbox_text").css('color', '#666');
    }

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/82m9C/

Comment: @noWayhome did you try it with .css instead of style.color?

Comment: just tried it.  no luck.  is it working for you? can you bring up a fiddle?

Comment: when i check the checkbox on your fiddle nothing happens.  then i check that thing under the text and that text goes grey but i can't click it off...

Comment: ya the button makes it grey but doesn't revert it

Comment: @noWayhome it's working fine in Chrome.. what browser are you testing it with?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the "checked" attribute doesn't equal true, it equals "checked" or nothing

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp

**EDIT:**

Maybe try this:

```
$('#activate_post_checkbox').is(':checked');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mjgasner/M4Fhf/8/

Comment: if($("#activate_post_checkbox").attr("checked") == "checked") {

Comment: try reading this:

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-check-if-checkbox-is-checked.html

Comment: reading that the original way i had it looks like example one.

Comment: @noWayhome, **BTW**:  it's a "property", not an "attribute".  For jQuery 1.6 and above, use [jQuery's `.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `.attr()`.  It's a moot point anyway... `.is(':checked')` is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code around:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/kf4Jm/2/)

```
$(function() {
    $('#activate_post_checkbox_text').css('color', '#666666'); // sets color
    $('#activate_post_checkbox').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
           $('#activate_post_checkbox_text').css('color', 'black');
        } else {
           $('#activate_post_checkbox_text').css('color', '#666666');
        }    
    });
});
```

HTML (removed the inline js):

```
<li class="activate_post_checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="activate_post_checkbox" value="active" /><span id="activate_post_checkbox_text">Make my posting active immediately.</span>
    </li>
```